# Picklist (multi-select) component não atualiza os dados. BootStrap + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Bom dia, tenho uma tela de cadastro, uma `jsp` com um modal onde implementei um picklist baseado nos templates Bootstrap.

Eu preciso selecionar do meu banco as empresas (está fazendo isso) de um lado e passar para o outro lado as selecionadas (o que não faz), veja imagem.

[image: debug chrome]
AngularJS controller:

```
BoxApp.controller("CadastroCertificadoController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.clientes = {};

    $scope.iniciar = function() {
        $http.get('/boxmlV2/cadastrocertificado').success(function(response) {
            $scope.clientes = response;
        });
    };

    $scope.iniciar();
});
```

Meu component picklist na jsp:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Empresas:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select ng-model="certificadoIncluirAlterar.razaoSocial" multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" name="my_multi_select1[]">
            <option ng-repeat="c in clientes" value="{{c.idCliente}}">{{c.razaoSocial}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Meu Controller java (somente carrega dados da tabela cliente na tela):

```
@Controller
public class CadastroCertificadoController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteService clienteService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cadastrocertificado", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView iniciar(ModelMap modelMap) {
        return new ModelAndView("cadastrocertificado");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/cadastrocertificado", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody List<ClienteDTO> obterTodos(ModelMap modelMap){
        return clienteService.obterTodos();
    }
}
```

Não sei o que pode estar acontecendo, qualquer ajuda é válida. Obrigado.

Dados mockados, funcionam desta forma:

```
                                                <select ng-model="certificadoIncluirAlterar.razaoSocial" multiple="multiple" class="multi-select"
                                                id="my_multi_select1" name="my_multi_select1[]">
                                                <option>Teste 1 </option>
                                                <option>Teste 2 </option>
                                                <option>Teste 3 </option>
                                                <option>Teste 4 </option>
                                                <option>Teste 5 </option>
                                                <option>Teste</option>                                                  <
                                                <option selected>Teste 6</option>
                                                <option selected>Teste 7</option>

                                                </select>
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo a função para pegar da coluna da esquerda e jogar para a direita? É pelo Angular ou algum JS (ou js do bootstrap)?

Comment: Celsom, sou novo com Angular e js na verdade, é justamente isto que quero fazer. Só sei fazer mockando os dados, não tenho idéia como passar os dados pro outro lado. Editei a pergunta com o exemplo com os dados mockados, ai funciona mas pode ver que é uma tag que define o que foi pro outro lado.

Comment: Na verdade, apenas jogar para o outro lado, é simples. Mas, antes de elaborar a resposta, uma dúvida, qual a finalidade? Você vai cadastrar em um banco depois? Precisa ir com mais dados? Ou só a lista de empresas? Ou.. vai ser somente uma empresa ou podem ser múltiplas empresas?

Comment: Isto Celsom, os registros (lista) que serão passados pro lado direito (selecionado) vão ser enviados para o controller java onde vou salvar no banco. Precisa ir com o id da empresa e a razaosocial, preciso do id pra inserir no banco. Obrigadoo !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, a manipulação do dado `esquerda <-> direita` é relativamente simples.

Na teoria você precisa fazer o seguinte:

1. Ter uma array vazia;
2. Ter uma função para receber a empresa selecionada e passar para a direita;
3. Essa função irá receber os dados e adicionar na nova array, que até então estava vazia;
4. Uma função a parte para fazer o submit enviando os dados que você precisa;

Para criar a array vazia, recomendo que faça da seguinte forma:

```
$scope.novaLista = [];
$scope.novaLista['listaSeleciona'] = {};
var newArray; //vamos usar isso posteriormente
```

Deste modo você terá uma 'nested-array' podendo mandar outros dados juntos, se você sabe como funciona uma array, vai entender perfeitamente.

Para adicionar ela, basta usar o seguinte método:

```
$scope.novaLista['listaSeleciona'].push('newArray');
```

Assim você irá inserir a variável `newArray` dentro daquela lista, que estava reservada para exibir as empresas que serão selecionadas

Agora para gerar os dados a serem inseridos, vamos supor que a sua lista de empresas seja assim:

```
$scope.empresas = [
    {id:1, razao: 'Empresa ME', tel: '9966-5588'},
    {id:2, razao: 'Negócio ME', tel: '9966-5588'},
    //...
];
```

Você precisa agora selecionar a empresa que deseja adicionar, e chamar a função para fazer isso, que seria atribuída ao botão que fica entre as duas colunas.

```
$scope.adicionarEmpresa = function(data) {
    newArray = {id: data.id, razao: data.razao}; //Assim você seleciona só os campos que deseja. Conseguiu entender a lógica?
    $scope.novaLista['listaSeleciona'].push('newArray'); //Insere o novo objeto;
};
```

Para determinar qual objeto está selecionado, você pode fazer assim (não testei isso, então, teste antes):

```
<option ng-click="meuElemento = c" ng-repeat="c in clientes" value="{{c.idCliente}}">{{c.razaoSocial}}</option>
```

E o botão para chamar a função para adicionar a empresa use:

```
<button ng-click="adicionarEmpresa(meuElemento)">Adicionar</button> //é o botão com a seta dupla que tem na sua imagem
```

Essa é a lógica geral, agora você precisa aplicar ao seu modelo, pois você possuí outros dados e, inclusive, um input de envio de arquivos.

Comment: A resposta do @CelsomTrindade está ótima, fiz um exemplo rápido pois estou um pouco sem tempo, mas basicamente seria isso: http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/HB7LU/22159/

Comment: Muito obrigado aos dois dei vote up tbm ! abs

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente !!!!!!!!!!!